# MS Access 2007 data type mismatch in Criteria Expression for string

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I have three fields called fileName,rowNo and rowText in Access 07 table named shortNotes. 
When I run this insert query it works perfect:

thisCommand.CommandText = "insert into shortNotes values('" + fName + "'," + rNo + ",'" + richTextBox2.Text +" |"+rNo+ "')";

But when I added parameters, It started throwing this error:
"data type mismatch in Criteria Expression"

Here is the code:

```
        dbCon = new OleDbConnection(MyconnectionString);
        dbCon.Open();
        thisCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        thisCommand.Connection = dbCon;

        thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@rowtext", OleDbType.BSTR);
        thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", OleDbType.BSTR);
        thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@rno", OleDbType.Integer);

        thisCommand.Parameters["@rowtext"].Value = richTextBox2.Text + " |" + rNo;

        thisCommand.Parameters["@file"].Value = fName;

        thisCommand.Parameters["@rno"].Value = rNo;

        thisCommand.CommandText = "insert into shortNotes values(@file,@rno,@rowtext)";
        thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//Error
```

Here file is memo, rno is number and rowtext is memo datatype in access 07.
What is the problem?

Comment: Note that OleDb can use named parameters: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857940/ms-access-named-parameters-and-column-names/20811933#20811933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is OleDb does NOT use named parameters.

"The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx

Check the example there..

Comment: Note that OleDb can use named parameters: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857940/ms-access-named-parameters-and-column-names/20811933#20811933

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, could it be something to do with your column lengths? You've specified the type as strings (well memo) but not the length - try using an overload ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325932%28v=vs.71%29)) that takes the optional parameter for length. For example, if your Access notes fields are 255 chars long:

```
thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@rowtext", OleDbType.BSTR, 255);
thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", OleDbType.BSTR, 255);
```

My worry is without this, it might assume that the length of your parameters is only 1 character long and so fall over when you try and set the value to something longer than this.

Answer (score 0):

What data types are these columns in your Access database?  Have you tried using VarChar instead of BSTR, or even just using Variant for the data types across the board?