# C# Parametized OLEDB Query using MS Access

Tags: c#, database, parameters, oledb

ok i do have a OLEDB function that inserts data in the database. well i know the usual way on how to do SQL with OLEDB but what I want to do here is to parametize each data in the query string.

Now I been in Google for almost 3 hours just know how to make parametized query in OLEDB but all of them are not working with me.

Now at last my query seems to work fine in the code below but still an error occurs

**my function code :**

```
private bool dbInsert(int [] inputNumbers, DateTime datetime){
                try {
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO 655(1stNum, 2ndNum, 3rdNum, 4thNum, 5thNum, 6thNum, datedraw) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?)";
                    OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, app.oleDbConn());
                    dbcmd.Connection.Open();
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[0];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[1];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[2];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[3];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[4];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.Numeric).Value = inputNumbers[5];
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add("?",OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = datetime;
                    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbcmd.Connection.Close();

                }catch(OleDbException ex){
                    showPrompt("Error reading the database",Color.Red);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                return true;
            }
```

**this is the error log show in the console:**

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria
>   expression.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

the datatypes of my columns in my access db files are **Numeric** from 1stNum to 6thNum and **Date/Time** in datedraw, of course ID is **AutoNumber**

is there any mistake in the parametize query implementation? please help me.

**Update**

- I change the OleDBType for nums to **Numeric** as in the Access file its **Numeric**

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) says that `DBDateTime` must be in the format `yyyymmddhhmmss`.  It doesn't look like you are formatting it.  Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @cadrel let me check it thanks

Comment: sorry still the same error :(

Comment: Can you reduce the query to a single parameter?

Comment: @cadrell0 thank you, the thing works with setting the date with the right format. I discovered it by directly putting the numbers in the query. But I want this numbers to be parametize..

Comment: @cadrell0 an MS Access File(.mdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around the values, like this:

```
String sql = 
    "INSERT INTO 655(1stNum, 2ndNum, 3rdNum, 4thNum, 5thNum, 6thNum, datedraw)
    VALUES('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' ,'?')";
```

Also, have you tried inserting a real integer instead of `"?"` ?

Comment: what about the datedraw parameter? its datetime

Comment: ok i tried putting directly the numbers in the query it works..  but why? is there any mistake with the oledbtype?

Comment: That's because you're setting the value to be an integer but passing in a question mark, which isn't an integer.

Comment: sorry I don't got the point, I want my numbers to be passed as parameters in the query. I already tried removing the quotations from the first place.. still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would check is the type: OleDbType.DBTimeStamp

If I recall, TimeStamp is a special type that's not easily compatible with the DateTime type.

Note that OleDb CAN use named parameters: see [MS Access, Named parameters and Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857940/ms-access-named-parameters-and-column-names/20811933#20811933)