# Update Rows Data in Database ms Access With Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

i use Database ms Access, and i try to Update some Rows with use parameters like code below

```
OleDbCommand cmdEditOffline = new OleDbCommand();
cmdEditOffline.CommandText = "UPDATE  TbTransactionToOffline SET Amount = @Amount  WHERE NoRef = @NoRef";
cmdEditOffline.Connection = conn;
cmdEditOffline.Parameters.Add("@Amount", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAmount.Text;
cmdEditOffline.Parameters.Add("@NoRef", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = label1.Text;`
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
cmdEditOffline.ExecuteNonQuery();
this.Close();
```

i hope is that the data is updated in accordance with the parameters, but instead all data is updated.
what wrong?

Comment: You are adding the values in a strange way. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database

Comment: Access don't support named parameters. Read the remarks section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually named parameters are supported.  Not sure at what version.  MSDN implies Office 2010.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845220%28v=office.14%29.aspx.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857940/ms-access-named-parameters-and-column-names.  Regardless, since the op is not using the proper format for named parms, he is using them in order which would work.  I would guess his where clause wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmdEditOffline.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtAmount.Text);
cmdEditOffline.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoRef", label1.Text);
```